# as our enemies are joining forces

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, adverbial-phrases

a. As our enemies are joining forces, so should we.

b. We should join forces as our enemies are.

c. We should join forces, as our enemies are.

Which could mean

1. We should join forces **because** our enemies are.

?

I think they could all mean

2. We should join forces **while** our enemies are.
3. We should join forces **in the same way** our enemies are.

Is that correct?

Many thanks.

Comment: It should really be "...as our enemies **do**", because "join" is something you do, not something you are.

Comment: Thank you Stangdon. The idea was that We should join forces as our enemies are JOINING FORCES.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's ambiguous.  It might be good ambiguity (you can pack two meanings into one sentence) or bad ambiguity (the intended meaning is unclear), or not real ambiguity (if the context and background knowledge makes the intent clear).